# Flex XML descendents

Tags: xml, apache-flex

i have complex XML structure i want get all descendents uisng some xml paren.child.@attribute representation

For example

```
<employes>
<employe id="a123">
    <month name="jan" sales="100" target="110">
        <task  sale="100" target="110"/>
    </month>
    <month name="Feb" sales="150" target="150">
        <task  sale="75" target="75"/>
        <task  sale="75" target="75"/>
    </month>
</employe>
<employe id="b123">
    <month name="dec" sales="50" target="100">
        <task  sale="50" target="100"/>
    </month>
    <month name="jan" sales="100" target="110">
        <task  sale="100" target="110"/>
    </month>
    <month name="Feb" sales="150" target="150">
        <task  sale="75" target="75"/>
        <task  sale="75" target="75"/>
    </month>
</employe>
```

Suppose i want get all xml nodes with month.task.@target   how can i implement this, 
I mean i only give input as "month.task.@target" and the return should be XMLList containing all node that have same structure
can any one help me please
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the ".." operator.

Your query should look something like:

```
employes..task
```

This will return all "task" nodes on any level.

You can also add filtering on the attributes:

```
employes..task(@target == 75)
```

Comment: If not all of your elements contain the target attribute, flex will throw an error. You can use the ..task(attribute('target') == 75) syntax instead to prevent this. I thought this was worth mentioning here as it took me a long time to track this down in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for replying , I know the XML descendent operator,  My problem is like Flex datagrid allows to define datagridcolumn in MXML and setting datafield values as path to the entire XML node. i would need to create a similar component, but it follows coplex  representation

like

1. datafield="month .@name" />

for that my itemrenderer shoud process the each data object and construct the childs as image i have attched